# Is there a directive receiving all HTTP methods in spray?

Tags: scala, routes, spray

The example with HTTP GET with spray [is simple](http://spray.io/documentation/1.1-SNAPSHOT/spray-routing/getting-started/):

```
import spray.routing.SimpleRoutingApp

object Main extends App with SimpleRoutingApp {
  implicit val system = ActorSystem("my-system")

  startServer(interface = "localhost", port = 8080) {
    path("hello") {
      get {
        complete {
          <h1>Say hello to spray</h1>
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So if I want execute HTTP POST I can use the `post` directive. But how can I deliver response to all HTTP methods? Something like this:

```
startServer(interface = "localhost", port = 8080) {
path("hello") {
  all { // - here something like all derective
    complete ("I do not care.")
    }
  }
}
```

Is there `all` directive or something similar?

Answer (score 2):

`get` is a filter directive to filter HTTP methods and allows only get to pass through. You don't need to have any filter directive.

So to allow all you can just not have any filter directive based on HTTP methods

```
import spray.routing.SimpleRoutingApp
object Main extends App with SimpleRoutingApp {
  implicit val system = ActorSystem("my-system")
  startServer(interface = "localhost", port = 8080) {
    path("hello") {
      complete {
          Say hello to spray
      }
    }
  }
}
```